# Declare objects as an attribute of another object in python

Tags: python, oop, nest-nested-object

I try to create a tree of objects / not classes. I mean i do not want to create relations between the objects in prototype level, but in instance level so the relations between the objects will be solved with the code.

Here i wrote something

```
class human :

    def  __init__ (self,Name,Surname,Gender,Age,Father,Mother) :

        self.Name = Name
        self.Surname = Surname
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Age = Age
        self.Father = Father
        self.Mother = Mother

class family :

    def __init__ (self,Surname,Members) :

        self.Surname = Surname
        self.Members = Members

    def ListMembers (self) :

        for member in self.Members :

            print (self.Surname +' family member ' +member.Name + ' '+ member.Surname + ' is ' + member.Age + " years old ")


human1 = human( 'Mary','Walter','Female','42','Jason White','Sally White')
human2 = human('Charles', 'Walter', 'Male', '45', 'Samuel Ribbon', 'Angie Ribbon')
human3 = human('Claire', 'White', 'Female', '16', 'Charles Walter', 'Mary Walter')

WalterFamily = family('Walter',(human1,human2,human3))

WalterFamily.ListMembers
```

When i run this code WalterFamily.ListMembers prints nothing.

What is exact way of nesting objects in another object ?
Like i tried to do here :  Nesting 3 humans inside a family and also reach to the attributes of these objects..

Comment: Functions need parens in order to be called.

Comment: In general, it is conventional to have uppercase class names and lowercase attribute names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of code is not what you want. All functions that belong to a class (like your `ListMembers` function) is a function stored in a variable name.

When you have what you currently have:

```
WalterFamily.ListMembers
```

You only print the function object stored at the `ListMembers` variable. To actually call it, you need to add parenthesis.

```
WalterFamily.ListMembers()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python everything is an object, including functions. So `WalterFamily.ListMembers` is just a reference to the object. To call the function you need `WalterFamily.ListMembers()`